# sum of Littlewood-Richardson coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, representation-theory

Let $c_{\lambda\mu}^\nu$ be the usual Littlewood-Richardson coefficients, which appear for example in the expansion of a product of Schur polynomials into Schur polynomials,
$$ s_\lambda(x)s_\mu(x)=\sum_\nu c_{\lambda\mu}^\nu s_\nu(x).$$

Is there an explicit formula for the sum
$$ \sum_\mu c_{\lambda\mu}^\nu$$
in terms of $\lambda$ and $\nu$? The Wikipedia page on the coefficients doesn't say anything about this.

(I *think* that if $\nu$ and $\lambda$ are both hooks, then the above sum equals the number of connected components in the skew diagram $\nu/\lambda$.)